# Coercing rvest to recognize tables (html_tag(x) == "table" is not TRUE)

Tags: r, rvest

I can't seem to ever get `html_table()` to work.

This is a perfect example:
(Trying to scrape the 6 Games: table)

```
library(rvest)

hockey <- html("http://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/2015/3/6/")

hockey %>%
    html_nodes("#stats .tooltip , #stats td , #stats a") %>%
    html_table()
```

But I am getting a `html_tag(x) == "table" is not TRUE`.
It's so obviously a table.

How can I coerce rvest to recognize the node as a table?

Comment: You've selected nodes inside the table, not the table itself, so none of the resulting nodes are, in fact, a table. Why not skip `html_nodes()` entirely? (You might need `fill = TRUE` in `html_table()`...)

Comment: @joran even "#stats td" doesn't work...

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Run `out <- hockey %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)` and then look at the first one, `out[[1]]`.

Comment: Also...`hockey %>% html_nodes("#stats") %>% html_table()` works fine as well. Again, the key is that you're selecting nodes internal to the table, not the table itself.

Comment: @joran both worked. If you want to convert your comments into an answer I can give you the checkmark!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try either:

```
hockey %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

to parse all the tables on the page, or

```
hockey %>% html_nodes("#stats") %>% html_table()
```

to parse just the first one you're after.